# How to Read IBM 4690 supermarket application file .DAT

Tags: c#

i have a `.DAT` file generated by `IBM 4690`  I'm unable to read it. Apparently it comes from the IBM 4690 Supermarket Application controller. I've done internet searches and nothing helpful comes up. The guy that sent it to me said he has never had to convert or read it into CSV or any other file format, so he can't provide any assistance. Can anyone help reading it using c# or any tool ?

Comment: Is the file binary then? Have you fired it up in a binary editor/viewer program?

Comment: not binary , and not formatted data

Comment: ـںˆ                                                   )                            ؤ  «‍ ?   d2                  ر            ùE    +ک     ¸          ‘       E   |ں                         %        D  Tn    ¢v  B   ­W          |       !ن  ‚ô    ©                       "(  ëü!    ي0                  G       #   ئ±                                  %                                         &¹      ڑ                  پ        Pî  Rئ

Comment: That looks binary to me. Open it in a hex editor?

Comment: i opened on https://hexed.it/ but how to convert  ?

Comment: when i check for Encoding for the file using c# i found '(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding)'

Comment: i ad file .DAT generated by IBM 4690 SW which contains transaction Log . how i can convert to readable file ?!

Comment: You can wait till some IBM expert comes by, back from retirement or you can provide some hex dumps to get some informed opinions.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is ultimately in the 4690/ACE documentation.  You need the IBM 4690 or ACE "Programming Reference" (not the programming guide).  You can find it at: [IBM ACE Programming Reference](http://www.pdffiller.com/1542117-boc0mstpdf-SurePOS-ACE-Programming-Reference---ibmcom-Other-forms).  I apologize for sending you to such a questionable website.  Unfortunately, since Toshiba took over IBM ACE, these documents are **hard to find**.

On the IBM 4680/4690/ACE systems, the transaction logs are EAMTRANA, EAMTRANB, EAMTRANC.  They roll over.  At any one time, one of these is prime.  They always roll over in this fashion: A, B, C, A, B, C, etc...  In the default configuration, only two (2) of these TLOGs actually have data in them.

So search the document for EAMTRAN.  You'll find it.

Parsing the TLOG is difficult.  Is a combination of binary and ascii data.  From a high level, the TLOG is comprised of double-quoted strings terminated by CRLF.  Fields are generally separated by colon (':') characters.  Some fields are plain ASCII, some are BCD, and others are pure binary.  Because some are binary, you have to know exactly what you're parsing.  You can't just use the pattern of "*"\r\n to parse out these "strings", because a binary field might actually have "\r\n in it.  Be Careful.

I'm guessing that you're interested in the actual sales tickets -- that's just a guess, though - I am not clear on exactly what kind of data you wish to extract.  These files contain sales information, among many other things (logons, logoffs, etc).  Search the documentation for the text "transaction header string", "item entry string" and "item entry extension string".  That should get you on your way.  You'll have to write a program that reads this data and makes sense out of it...

Comment: Hi Code4aliving, I am working on parsing a eamitemr.dat and wondered if you were open to a professional consult about it?  Sorry for contacting you via comment but Stack Overflow doesn't seem to have any other method

Comment: Hi user441669, I'm sorry that I missed this...it's been a very busy couple of months for me.  The eamitemr.dat file is a keyed file, and you'd normally access it that way.  However, you *CAN* parse through it and pull item records out of it.  The first 512 bytes is a header block.  The record length is encoded as an intel short at decimal offset 46.  The key length (6 or 7) is encoded as an intel short at decimal offset 54.  The subsequent 512 byte blocks have data.  The 512 byte data blocks are 4 bytes header, then 'n' item records.  Records with a zero ITEMCODE are ignored.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link I provided to the IBM ACE Programming Reference no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

the 4690 system has a tool for viewing data file, their hex editor if you will, adxcsj0l. as to exactly what the data is? that's the difficult part as mostly the file layouts are not published.

Answer (score 0):

The TLOG file is in binary format. Please use any of the Hex editor tools to view the contents of the file but before that you should be well versed about TLOG strings to understand the transaction details.